# Designing an efficient reducer for a large state with redux

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am using redux with react and typescript for my application. I am working with many items used at different places of my app. My state looks like this:

```
{
    items: {42: {}, 53: {}, ... }, //A large dictionary of items
    itemPage1: {
        items: [42, 34, 67, ...],
        ...
    },
    itemPage2: { ... 
    },
    ...
}
```

I want to write an efficient item reducer, but the items are big and I cannot create deep copies each time. Apparently I don't need to according to gaearon (extracted from [there](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/768)): ***Redux does not ask you to deeply clone the state on every action. It just asks you to return new objects for the parts that have changed. You can reuse the previous state for any parts of the tree that have not changed.*** .

This is great! However I am new to all this and I am not sure how to implement the reducer correctly. What I have so far inside my item reducer is this:

```
case UPDATE_ITEM_LABEL:
    return (<any>Object).assign({}, state, {
          item_id: (<any>Object).assign({}, state[action.item_id], {
              label: action.value
          })
    })
```

So it copies all the element of the old state into a new object, and then merge the result with an altered object with the new updated value. My hope is that the items during the first `assign` are passed by reference and therefore not deeply copied? If this is the case that would be fine as I can afford to deeply copy one item and some simple references for each actions. Also I found that it was possible to use immutable.js to answer this problem, if the method I propose is working, why would people use immutable.js ?

Comment: Immutable tries to be efficient about reusing existing data. The purpose is to avoid having to make decisions like that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a quick test to be sure that my method was doing the job:

```
var item1 = {prop1: 'item1', prop2: 'haha'};
var item2 = {prop1: 'item2', prop2: 'hehe'};
var items = {1:item1, 2:item2};

console.log(items);
```

This display as expected:

```
[object Object] {
  1: [object Object] {
    prop1: "item1",
    prop2: "haha"
  },
  2: [object Object] {
    prop1: "item2",
    prop2: "hehe"
  }
}
```

Now we use `assign` to get the next state, modifying one of the key for item2:

```
var items = Object.assign({},items, { 2: Object.assign({}, items[2],
    {
        prop2: 'huhu' 
    })
});

console.log(items);
```

This display as expected:

```
[object Object] {
  1: [object Object] {
    prop1: "item1",
    prop2: "haha"
  },
  2: [object Object] {
    prop1: "item2",
    prop2: "huhu"
  }
}
```

Now the interesting bit, if we use the initial reference to item1 and item2 to alter the `prop1` properties:

```
item1.prop1 = 'ITEM1'
item2.prop1 = 'ITEM2'

console.log(items);
```

We find out that only item2 was deeply copied, which is the behavior I want:

```
[object Object] {
  1: [object Object] {
    prop1: "ITEM1",
    prop2: "haha"
 },
  2: [object Object] {
    prop1: "item2",
    prop2: "huhu"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should break this up into separate reducers and use `combineReducers`